# I am getting error 405 when running this Django program via drf

Tags: python, django, postman

This code is for user registration through API, but when I try to test it with Postman, it gives error 405. Can you test the program and tell me where the problem is?

I first created an account, then added it to my project settings and URL You can see the rest of the work below:

views:

```
from rest_framework.response import Response
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from .serializers import UserRegisterSerializer


class UserRegister(APIView):
     def post(self, request):
        ser_data = UserRegisterSerializer(data=request.POST)
        if ser_data.is_valid():
            User.objects.create_user(
                username=ser_data.validated_data['username'],
                email=ser_data.validated_data['email'],
                password=ser_data.validated_data['password'],
                )
            return Response(ser_data.data)
        return Response(ser_data.errors)
```

serializers:

```
class UserRegisterSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    username = serializers.CharField(required=True)
    email = serializers.EmailField(required=True)
    password = serializers.CharField(required=True, write_only=True)
```

URLs:

````
from . import views


app_name = 'accounts'
urlpatterns = [
    path('register/', views.UserRegister.as_view()),
]```
````

and error:

[image]

Comment: You are sending a GET but you have to send a POST. And be aware that some redirects convert a POST to a GET.

Comment: The image you added is not of postman but of django itself. Update the HTTP method you are using instead of GET select POST in postman and then it will work.